# What's the proper way to center the UIRefreshControl above a scrolling UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

Scenario: Refresh Control containing image views.

I'm sure this problem has been experienced:

1. Create a UIRefreshControl upon a UICollectionView.
2. Do a horizontal scroll to notice that the UIRefreshControl is skewed.

[image]

Here's the setup code:

```
- (void)setupRefreshControl {
    self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refresh Data"];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor;
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    UIImage *hook = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hook"];
    UIImageView *hookImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hook];
    UIImage *fish = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fish"];
    UIImageView *fishImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fish];

    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithArrangedSubviews:@[hookImageView ,fishImageView]];
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.spacing = 10.0;
    [self.refreshControl addSubview:stackView];

    [stackView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    UILayoutGuide *container = [_refreshControl layoutMarginsGuide];
    [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.topAnchor].active = YES;
    CGFloat width = self.refreshControl.bounds.size.width;
    [stackView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.leftAnchor constant:width/2].active = YES;
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.collectionView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
}
```

As you can see, the `UIRefreshControl` is off-centered upon a horizontal scroll. Do I need to always calculate the new center?

There must be a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way should be centering the stack view with auto layout, and I would not embed the stack view inside of a refresh control. The following constraints (except the 20.0 which you should adapt to your needs) should place the stack view on the right position:

```
stackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[stackView.centeredXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.centeredXAnchor constant:0.0].active = YES; 
[stackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.topAnchor constant:20.0].active = YES;
```

You should also add an activity view (or animate the fish icon) and a label to the stack view, and you have to handle the bouncing by yourself.

Comment: I couldn't get your suggestion to work on my end.  However I did manage to center the UIRefreshControl via my solution posted above.   I was missing a couple of anchors.  ....albeit its behavior is a bit weird to my liking.

Comment: My suggestion was to dispense of the control.

Comment: This was a coding challenge that required the use of the control.   Yet I would agree that removing the control would make life easier.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee: Too bad, and I didn't win a prize. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple oversight: 
I merely needed an addition anchors to center the UIRefreshControl:

```
- (void)setupRefreshControl {
    // Refresh Control:
    self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    self.collectionView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;

    [_refreshControl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    UILayoutGuide *refreshControlContainer = [_collectionView layoutMarginsGuide];
    [_refreshControl.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:refreshControlContainer.topAnchor constant: 1.0].active = YES;
    [_refreshControl.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:refreshControlContainer.leftAnchor constant: 1.0].active = YES;
    [_refreshControl.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:300.0].active = YES;

    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refresh Data"];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor;
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

     // StackView members:
    UIImage *hook = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hook"];
    UIImageView *hookImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hook];
    UIImage *fish = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fish"];
    UIImageView *fishImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fish];

    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithArrangedSubviews:@[hookImageView ,fishImageView]];
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.spacing = 10.0;
    [self.refreshControl addSubview:stackView];

    // StackView:
    [stackView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    UILayoutGuide *stackViewContainer = [_refreshControl layoutMarginsGuide];
    [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:stackViewContainer.topAnchor].active = YES;
    CGFloat width = self.refreshControl.bounds.size.width;
    [stackView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:stackViewContainer.leftAnchor constant:width/2].active = YES;

    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
```